# How to specify public-read policy on a complete bucket in aws?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket named foo inside which resides my two subfolders named bar and foobar.

**Hierarchy**

```
foo
  -bar
  -foobar
```

**Problem**

Now i want to make my uploaded objects public readable. Using xhr (by allowing CORS) i was able to do so. But using ***AWS android sdk*** the public-read acl is still not implemented in their api as specified by this [feature request on GITHUB](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/63)

So as evident i am not able to make my uploaded objects using ***AWS Android sdk***

So please help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done via S3 bucket policy. See [Bucket Policy Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html). It looks like what you need is to allow anonymous read to objects under a bucket. You can apply the following bucket policy to the bucket `foo`.

```js
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::foo/bar/*","arn:aws:s3:::foo/foobar/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

This should also answer the question on [Github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/63).

Comment: And can i add more principals , like myself using AWS-ACCOUNT-ID ?

Comment: That works for me ..Thanks alot, but can you answer my question in the first comment ?

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't it make objects private to the account? And you need credentials of that account to access them.

Comment: What i meant in the first comment was , if i can have a AWS-ACCOUNT-ID parallel(in a separate statement block) to a *(asterisk) ?

That second statement can be say, allowing only a put to myself(owner)

Comment: Yes. You can apply multiple statements, one of which has your account id as principle. FYI, yourself as owner should always have full permission to the bucket. So that statement may not be useful. The access control becomes muddy with bucket policy and IAM policy. Please read http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/TxPOJBY6FE360K/IAM-policies-and-Bucket-Policies-and-ACLs-Oh-My-Controlling-Access-to-S3-Resourc for more information.

Comment: If you have further question about S3 access control, it'd be better to raise a new question to draw more attentions.

Answer (score 0):

The transfer manager currently does not support ACL; however, you can use `AmazonS3Client` to perform [`putObject()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#putObject%28com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest%29). You can take a look at the AWS Mobile SDK for Android [API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#setCannedAcl%28com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList%29) for more details.

Comment: `AmazonS3Client` is not deprecated.

Comment: Okay. Thanks, but as i have already implemented most of the stuff now, taking this path would require more time than i can afford. But good to know it.